# Delphi 7 changing parameters from integer to shortint

Tags: delphi

I am having an issue where closing and reopening the file in the IDE will change parameters (tparam) for my dataset from integer to shortint.  If i change them to integer it appears to save, but once lcosed and reopened it is back as shortint.  **is there a way around Delphi changing parameters from Integer to Shortint**?

I found a similar issue here
http://www.delphigroups.info/2/1/284088.html

It appears a bug, but there **is there a workaround of some fashion?** Upgraded Delphi version is not something I can do at this moment. (reproduction steps outlined in second edit)

EDIT:

This is happening by just placing a TQUERY on the form putting an sql statement in it with a parameter, if you change the value type to integer. save and reopen the value type is then shortint.

EDIT again:

In Delphi 7, create new application.  Drop a TQUery on the form.  Edit the SQL script to something like 'select * from table where id = :idnumber.  Edit the params next. Select idnumber and change VALUE.TYPE to Integer.  At this point you can save the file and close.  When you reopen the file.  And go to params again selecting idnumber it will remain a type ftInteger but the value.type will be Shortint.  This is the piece I wish to remain an integer, but unfortunately is getting converted to a shortint.

Comment: What is the underlying database type (Paradox, ADO, etc.) and field type?

Comment: The `TQuery` has to be connecting to a database somewhere. If it's an actual `TQuery`, that's attached to a BDE database of some sort (as I said, Paradox or something else through BDELinks). It could be related to the database driver or the underlying DB column data type, which is why I asked (and will again): What is the underlying database type and field type? (If the DB column is `shortint`, there's no need to save a parameter pointing to it as an `integer`, because the column can't hold more than a `shortint` value.)

Comment: And I will also say again. there is no database associated with the TQuery component.  All you have to do is drop a tquery on a form, add an sql statement with a parameter, assign the parameter value.type to integer and hit save.  When you reopen the form it will say "shortint" instead.  There is no database associated with the tquery just a component on a form.

Comment: I just tried exactly that: I created a new D7 app, dropped a `TQuery` on it, clicked the `SQL` button in the Object Inspector, typed in `SELECT ID FROM sometable WHERE ID = :id`, and closed the SQL edit window. Inspecting the form as text, I get one parameter declared (`ID`), with a `DataType = ftUnknown` and a `ParamType = ptUnknown`, neither of which are `integer`, and therefore aren't saved as `integer`.

Comment: if you first change the parameter to value.type of Integer (which auto changes the datatype to ftInteger) and save it, then close the form/pas file, then reopen, it will now be ftInteger with value.type of shortint. (at least in my environment).  The database will eventually matter but the issue is occurring either way, as to appear to be a bug in Tquery component or tdataset or something else.  This will eventually be on a Firebird database, but again that part isnt needed to create the issue.  it appears to occur with only the tquery component itself.

Comment: It does not go away when you add a database to it.  What I'm providing are the shortest steps to recreate the issue (Which is what is usually asked for).  And i'm unsure how its not clear.  I've stated three separate ways that you have to change the value.type of the parameter to integer prior to saving. Its in multiple comments and the main post.  This does not have to do with the database. this has something to do with the component itself or a component it inherits from. Thx

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem at all, so I'm afraid I can't help. I tried changing to `ftInteger`, saving again, and then closing and reopening, and it remained `ftInteger`. I'll delete my comments above so they don't influence anyone else, but you should probably edit your question to include the additional information you've provided in your comments. Good luck. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your time, also its not the ftInteger piece changing its the value.type changing to shortint.  I'll reassert that in the post.

Comment: When the query is executed (in the actual application) an integer will be assigned (much larger than a shortint) will (at that time) the valuetype be automatically upgrade to integer?  Because if it is short int during that time it will for sure be too large to fit into a shortint. Thx

Comment: It doesn't matter. See my answer. This is just a visual issue at design time, not a bug, and won't affect your actual running application.

Comment: Okay thanks. So me changing that value to "integer" is not preparing it for receiving a integer(longint) when assigned, its merely describing the 0 (zero) displayed in the IDE.  And in fact the only thing that matters is the ftInteger field type.  Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can explain the behavior you're seeing, and it's not a bug. (Your question is misleading, BTW. Your actual question, based on the edits and comments, is "Delphi 7 changing Parameter.Value.Type from integer to shortint", which is not the same thing at all.)

You're inspecting the `Value.Type` of the `Param.Value`, which is not stored in the `.dfm` file. `Value.Type` is set either when the form is streamed in from the `dfm` and the `Value` is read, or when `Value` is set at runtime.

I can demonstrate this by following your steps exactly:

Drop a TQuery on a new blank form. Add some SQL to the `TQuery.SQL`. I used `SELECT Id FROM SomeTable WHERE Id = :id`.

Click on the `...` for the `TQuery.Params`, and then the `id` parameter when the `Parameter Editor` dialog appears. Click the `Value` in the Object Inspector, and change the `Value.Type` to `Integer`.

Save the project and form, and close them. Reopen the project, right-click on the form, and choose `View as Text` from the context menu. You'll see the following for the `Query1` component:

```
object Query1: TQuery
  SQL.Strings = (
    'select id from sometable where id = :id')
  Left = 152
  Top = 80
  ParamData = <
    item
      DataType = ftInteger
      Name = 'id'
      ParamType = ptInput
      Value = 0
    end>
end
```

Note that in the `ParamData`, there is no `Value.Type`; that's because it's set when the `Value` is read, not stored when the form is saved.

Now right-click again, and choose `View as Form`. Go back to the `Query1.Parameters`, edit the `Value`, and set it to a high number (I used `123456789`).

Save the form, and then `View as Text` again. Note the `Query1` information:

```
object Query1: TQuery
  SQL.Strings = (
    'select id from sometable where id = :id')
  Left = 152
  Top = 80
  ParamData = <
    item
      DataType = ftInteger
      Name = 'id'
      ParamType = ptInput
      Value = '123456789'
    end>
end
```

Note that there is still no stored `Value.Type`. Check the Object Inspector for the `ValueType`, and it now says `String`, even though the Parameter.DataType is still `ftInteger`. This is caused by the IDE's streaming mechanism seeing the quotes, and setting the `Value.Type` accordingly.

Again, it has no impact on your running application. The `Value.Type` in the IDE doesn't matter.

Interesting side note: After seeing the `Value.Type` as `String` as mentioned above, if you view the form as text again, remove the `'` characters around the `Value` property, and `View as Form`, then check the `Value.Type` of the parameter again, it becomes `Integer`. This is a further indication that it's set during the streaming process, and at design-time has no meaning.

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much.  This was discovered when tracking down a bug related to parameters of a query being of the wrong type.  So this must not have been the cause and was not an issue.  The explanation is appreciated nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple way to convert the type of variables that have the same image (byte count) use the **absolute** keyword:

```
function wordToSmallInt(w : word) : smallInt; inline;
   {$WARN UNSAFE_CODE OFF}
   s : smallInt absolute w;
   {$WARN UNSAFE_CODE ON}
begin
   result := s;
end;
```

This, of course, works similarly with all data types that have the same size.